# I have to create an array with elements divided by 5 (Javscript) Sush us 5 10 15 20 ...60 (From 5 minutes to 60 minutes)

Tags: javascript

```
const minutes = [
  {
    value: "00",
    id: 1,
  },

  {
    id: 2,
    value: "05",
  },

  {
    id: 3,
    value: "10",
  },

  {
    id: 4,
    value: "15",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    value: "20",
  },

  {
    id: 6,
    value: "25",
  },

  {
    id: 7,
    value: "30",
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    value: "35",
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    value: "40",
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    value: "45",
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    value: "50",
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    value: "55",
  },
];
```

How can i make like this dynamically

Comment: How about the other way around? You need to run from 1 to 12, then create an object with id: currentIndex, value: toString((currentIndex - 1) * 5)

Comment: [Loops/iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [luk2302's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2442804/luk2302) comment to implement,

```js
let arr = []
for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  arr.push({
    id: (i + 1).toString(),
    value: (i * 5).toString()
  })

}

console.log(arr)
```